How to prevent Tippecanoe from dropping features?
I have a huge geojson with electric lines and columns. So I need to convert the file into vector tiles for displaying on my OpenLayers map. I use this sequence of commands:
tippecanoe --no-feature-limit --no-tile-size-limit --no-tile-compression -o electric.mbtiles electric.geojson
mb-util --image_format=pbf electric.mbtiles electric

These commands give me XYZ structure of vector tiles as expected. Unfortunately, some features are missing. I assume tippecanoe performs some decluttering or so. This is original GEOJSON:

And this is the corresponding tile (you can see 1 point - column - missing):

How can I prevent this?

You can set a base zoom using -B zoomlevel. This is the zoom level at which features are no longer dropped. By default, it is the maximum zoom level of your vector tile set—you should be seeing all of the features from your input data when zoomed to maximum in your vector tiles.
You could set your base zoom to 1, but this will largely defeat the purpose of using vector tiles. An untiled vector format like FlatGeoBuf might be more appropriate in that case.
Lastly, you can eliminate the mbutil step by replacing -o electric.mbtiles with -e electric in your tippecanoe command.
